# Clicking out of RadzenNumeric element with value higher than max does not reset the value

Tags: validation, input, blazor, radzen

I have a RadzenNumeric element defined like this,

```
<RadzenNumeric @bind-Value="Amount" Min="0.00M" Max="10000000.00M"/>
<ValidationMessage For="@(() => Amount)" />
```

Where `Amount` is of type `decimal`

So when I enter a value that is greater than 10000000, say 20000000 and click out of the element, the value in the input field resets to the max value i.e. 10000000. But if I manually change the value to 20000000 again and click out of the field once more, the number does not change as is expected.

I have no clue why. I tried the example provided in blazor radzen library documentation https://blazor.radzen.com/numeric and there it works as expected. Need help to figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: Is this really the code you are using? `@bindValue` is not the correct syntax.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine, we have used `@bind-Value` in our code. While typing out this question I probably entered the wrong syntax. I'll edit my question. Also, I'm sure that the code works since when I enter all correct information in the form I am able to submit all data into the db.

Comment: Yeah, I figured, but the fact some of the code was wrong could imply that you did not include other things that might matter. Do you get any error in the browser console? Is Blazor still responding correctly?

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine, I don't get any errors in the console and blazor responds correctly for all other fields. I'm wondering if this could be a problem with me binding the radzennumeric element to my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior was found to be a problem with the `RadzenNumeric` component. The component behaved like this whenever the `@bind-Value` property was used.

This bug was fixed by the Radzen team in release [v3.19.7](https://github.com/radzenhq/radzen-blazor/releases/tag/v3.19.7).

[Radzen forum thread](https://forum.radzen.com/t/clicking-out-of-radzennumeric-element-with-value-higher-than-max-does-not-reset-the-value/11228/2) identifying the bug.